# Finding Remaining Smaller Values in a Hash

Tags: algorithm, perl, hash

Cross-posted at http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=977333

Given the following hash:

```
my %hash = (1 => "i", 2 => "j", 3 => "k", 4=> "l");
```

and input pair

```
   my @pair  = (1,2);   
   my @pair2 = (2,3);  
   my @pair3 = (1,3);
   my @pair4 = (2,4);
```

We would like to find keys in `%hash` where the values is smaller than members
of any given pairs.

So the desired output for are:

```
@pair -> []
@pair2 -> [1]
@pair3 -> [2]
@pair4 -> [1,3]
```

What's the right algorithm to do that?
The following is my code but fail:

```
sub get_output {
     my ($inputhash,$pair) = @_;

  my @output = ();
  my %done = ();
  foreach my $pr (@{$pair}){
     foreach my $kn (keys %{$inputhash}){
             next if ($pr <= $kn || $done{$kn});
             push @output,$kn;  
             $done{$kn} = 1;

     }
  }

  use Data::Dumper;
  print Dumper \@output;
  return @output;
}
```

Comment: What code? You seemed to have been abducted before you could finish posting your question.

Comment: You declare `$inputhash` but then use `$input_hash`.  You have three `{` but four `}`

Comment: @neversaint `$done{kn}` is a different value than `$done{$kn}`.

Comment: @TLP: oops. Thanks. I modified. The code was the simplification of the larger one I have.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't get it. How can we compare 'j', 'k', etc... to numbers (of which the pairs in your example consist)? Why do we have to compare values of hash to each element of pair - and not the minimum one?

Comment: What is the hash `%done` all about?  You set a key in it (why, when you have the key in the array?) and a value of 1 (why 1?), but then you don't use it for anything.

Comment: @raina77ow: the value 'j', 'k' etc is actually irrelevant. The use of hash is just to show that the 'complete' set is unordered.

Comment: Could you show us some relevant code then? You're trying to explain your problem in general, but expect to see a specific answer. It's difficult to guess the missing details, don't you think?

Comment: First write a subroutine that will return the smallest N values from a list. For example: `smallest_n(2, keys %hash)` would return `[1,2]`. With that subroutine it hand, your main problem will be easy to solve: just compare the values in any given `@pair` to the values returned from `smallest_n()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very efficient but it works. Still don't see the point of the hash given your requested output doesn't involve the hash.:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my %hash = (1 => "i", 2 => "j", 3 => "k", 4=> "l");
my @pair = (1,2); #tested all your cases and it showed to work
my $it;
my $iterator;
my $sit;
my @occurence;
my @oldpair = @pair;
@occurence =  (0, 0, 0, 0);
foreach(@oldpair)
{
if ($_ == 1)
{
    $occurence[0] += 1;
}
if ($_ == 2)
{
    push(@pair, 1);
    $occurence[0] += 1;
    $occurence[1] += 1;
}
if ($_ == 3)
{
    push(@pair, 2);
    $occurence[1] += 1;
    $occurence[2] += 1;
}
if ($_ == 4)
{
    push(@pair, 3);
    $occurence[2] += 1;
    $occurence[3] += 1;
}
}

foreach $iterator(@occurence)
{
    $it++;
    if ($iterator > 1)
    {
        @pair = grep { $_ != $it } @pair;
    }

}
foreach $sit(@oldpair)
{
    @pair = grep { $_ != $sit } @pair;
}
```

Comment: print @pair at the end to see